# React component render called twice without changing state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am rendering a simple react component, where **no state and props are set**

I am logging text to console only once inside the render function but it's logged twice:

```
rendering counter
rendering counter
```

Below is the code of the component counter.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Counter extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log("rendering counter");       //this is printed two times

    return <span className={"badge m-3 badge-primary"}>counter</span>;
  }
}
export default Counter;
```

And index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import Counter from "./components/counter";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Counter />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

it seems that the render function in the component is called two times. But why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it was written in [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects):

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic. This is done by intentionally `double-invoking` the following methods:

- Class component constructor method
- The render method
- setState updater functions (the first argument)
- The static getDerivedStateFromProps lifecycle
- The shouldComponentUpdate method