# Do I have to worry about useState causing a re-render?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, use-state, wordpress-gutenberg

NB: I've asked this on wordpress.stackexchange, but it's not getting any response there, so trying here.

I'm not sure if this is WordPress specific, WordPress's overloaded React specific, or just React, but I'm creating a new block plugin for WordPress, and if I use `useState` in its `edit` function, the page is re-rendered, even if I never call the setter function.

```
import { useState } from '@wordpress/element';

export default function MyEdit( props ) {
        const {
                attributes: {
                    anAttribute
                },
                setAttributes,
        } = props;

        const [ isValidating, setIsValidating ] = useState( false );
        const post_id = wp.data.select("core/editor").getCurrentPostId();
        console.log('Post ID is ', post_id);

        const MyPlaceholder = () => {
            return(
                <div>this is a test</div>
            );
        };

        const Component = MyPlaceholder;

        return <Component />;
}
```

If I comment out `const [ isValidating, setIsValidating ] = useState( false );` then that `console.log` happens once. If I leave it in, it happens twice; even if I never check the value of `isValidating`, never mind calling `setIsValidating`. I don't want to over-optimize things, but, equally, if I use this block `n` times on a page, the page is getting rendered `2n` times. It's only on the admin side of things, because it's in the `edit`, so maybe not a big deal, but ... it doesn't seem right. Is this expected behavior for `useState`? Am I doing something wrong? Do I have to worry about it (from a speed perspective, from a potential race conditions as everything is re-rendered multiple times)?

Comment: if you got the answer kindly accept

Comment: Playing with your answer right now — once I confirm it works, I'll definitely accept!

Comment: sure thanx for the update, kindly let me know so that I can help more

Answer (score 2):

In your example code, the `console.log` statement is being immediately evaluated each time and triggering the redraw/re-rendering of your block. Once `console.log` is removed, only the state changes will trigger re-rendering.

As the Gutenberg Editor is based on Redux, if the state changes, any components that rely on that state are re-rendered. When a block is *selected* in the Editor, the selected block is rendered synchronously while all other blocks in the Editor are rendered asynchronously. The WordPress Gutenberg developers are aware of re-rendering being a [performance concern](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/architecture/performance/) and have taken steps to reduce re-rendering.

When requesting data from wp.data, `useEffect()` should be used to safely await asynchronous data:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from '@wordpress/element';

    export default function MyEdit(props) {
    ...
    const [curPostId, setCurPostId] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function getMyPostId() {
            const post_id = await wp.data.select("core/editor").getCurrentPostId();
            setCurPostId(post_id);
        }
        getMyPostId();
    }, []); // Run once

    const MyPlaceholder = () => {
        return (
             <div>Current Post Id: {curPostId}</div>
        );
    };

    const Component = MyPlaceholder;

    return <Component />;
}
```

As mentioned in the question, `useState()` is used in core blocks for setting and updating state. The state hook was introducted in [React 16.8](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html), its a fairly recent change and you may come across older Gutenberg code example that set state via the class constructor and don't use hooks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to worry about always put an array of dependencies, so that, it won't re-render, As per your query, let's say are planning to edit a field here is the sample code

```
const [edit, setEdit]= useState(props);

useEffect(() => {
// logic here
},[edit])
```

that `[edit]` will check if there is any changes , and according to that it will update the DOM, if you don't put any [](array of dependencies) it will always go  an infinite loop,

Comment: Hmm. I don't think this is quite it. First, if I add a `useEffect` the stuff inside of it indeed only happens once, but the page is still rendered twice (or, at least, the `MyEdit` function is called twice). Second, there are lots of examples in the WordPress core of blocks that use `useState` without using `useEffect` (e.g., button, html, social-link, and others).

Comment: write the function using async await and bind it inside the useEffect, I am not sure for Wordpress but give it a shot, using useState is not the problem for your re render, somewhere you have missed up,

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is expected behavior. If I add a similar `console.log` to native core blocks that use `useState`, I get the same effect. It seems that WordPress operates with `use strict`, and according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60840401/11020164), React double-invokes a number of things when in strict mode.